# Using pre-trained sentence embedding on recurrent networks

Tags: python, keras, deep-learning, nlp, embedding

I want to use [Universal Sentence Embedding](https://arxiv.org/abs/1803.11175) on recurrent networks.

So a traditional word embedding with RNN encodes each word into a vector and the RNN's time_step would be the number of words in a sentence.

What I want to do is to use the sentence embedding to encode each sentence into a 512-dim vector. The RNN's time_step would be the number of sentences in a text, or IMDB review in my case.

I am trying this on IMDB binary classification. The problem is that no matter how I tune the hyperparamters, the model will not learn. The training and test accuracies stay at 50%, which means that the model predicts only 1 out of the 2 classes.

I would appreciate any help!

```
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #
=================================================================
lstm_1 (LSTM)                (None, 128)               131584
_________________________________________________________________
dense_1 (Dense)              (None, 2)                 258
=================================================================
Total params: 131,842
Trainable params: 131,842
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
WARNING:tensorflow:From C:\Users\shaggyday\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\math_ops.py:3066: to_int32 (from tensorflow.python.ops.math_ops) is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
Instructions for updating:
Use tf.cast instead.
W0709 14:26:44.883890  9716 deprecation.py:323] From C:\Users\shaggyday\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\math_ops.py:3066: to_int32 (from tensorflow.python.ops.math_ops) is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
Instructions for updating:
Use tf.cast instead.
Epoch 1/10
249/249 [==============================] - 55s 220ms/step - loss: 0.6937 - acc: 0.5004 - val_loss: 0.6931 - val_acc: 0.5061
Epoch 2/10
249/249 [==============================] - 68s 274ms/step - loss: 0.6970 - acc: 0.5002 - val_loss: 0.6942 - val_acc: 0.5009
Epoch 3/10
249/249 [==============================] - 71s 285ms/step - loss: 0.6947 - acc: 0.4961 - val_loss: 0.6980 - val_acc: 0.5009
Epoch 4/10
249/249 [==============================] - 70s 279ms/step - loss: 0.6938 - acc: 0.4998 - val_loss: 0.6956 - val_acc: 0.5033
Epoch 5/10
249/249 [==============================] - 66s 267ms/step - loss: 0.6936 - acc: 0.5018 - val_loss: 0.6939 - val_acc: 0.5046
Epoch 6/10
249/249 [==============================] - 63s 251ms/step - loss: 0.6931 - acc: 0.5003 - val_loss: 0.6933 - val_acc: 0.5058
```

The code for pre embedding the text is

```
file = 'train.csv'
df = pd.read_csv(file)
# df['sentiment'] = [1 if sentiment == 'positive' else 0 for sentiment in df['sentiment'].values]
x = df['review'].values
y = df['sentiment'].values
x_sent = []
for review in x:
    x_sent.append(sent_tokenize( review ) )


num_sample = len(x)
val_split = int(num_sample*0.5)
x_train, y_train = x_sent, y
x_test, y_test = x_sent[val_split:], y[val_split:]

module_url = "https://tfhub.dev/google/universal-sentence-encoder-large/2" 
out_dir = 'use(dan)'
embed = hub.Module(module_url)

num_files = 10
n_file = num_sample // num_files

for n in range( num_files ):

    def batch_embed( batch, labels, lens, set_ ):
        """
        batch:   1-D array of sentences
        labels:  labels for each reviews
        lens:    offsets for the reviews
        set_:    'train' | 'test'
        """
        with tf.Session( config=config ) as session:
          session.run([tf.global_variables_initializer(), tf.tables_initializer()])
          
          print( 'Getting embeddings for the {} data'.format( set_ ) )
          path = os.path.join( out_dir, 'embed_{}_{}.bin'.format( set_ , n ) )
          if not os.path.exists( path ):
            embeddings = session.run( embed( batch ) )
            offset = 0
            review_embeddings = []
            for l in lens:
                review_embeddings.append( embeddings[ offset : offset + l ] )
                offset += l
            with open( path, 'wb' ) as f:
                pickle.dump( (review_embeddings, labels), f )
            
            for i, re in enumerate(embeddings):
                if re.shape[0]==0:
                    print( i, batch[i] )
    
    train_batch = x_train[ n * n_file : min( len( x_train ),  ( n + 1 ) * n_file )  ]
    labels = y_train[ n * n_file : min( len( x_train ),  ( n + 1 ) * n_file )  ]
    lens = [ len( x ) for x in train_batch ]
    sent_batch = [ sent for review in train_batch for sent in review ]
    print( len( sent_batch ) )
    batch_embed(sent_batch, labels, lens, 'train')

    test_batch = x_test[ n * n_file : min( len( x_test ),  ( n + 1 ) * n_file )  ]
    labels = y_test[ n * n_file : min( len( x_test ),  ( n + 1 ) * n_file )  ]
    lens = [ len( x ) for x in test_batch ]
    sent_batch = [ sent for review in test_batch for sent in review ]
    print( len( sent_batch ) )
    batch_embed(sent_batch, labels, lens, 'test')
```

The model is a very simple lstm with one layer and 256 neurons. Each batch is padded because each IMDB review has different number of sentences

Comment: It would help to have additional details such as the code that you use to define the model and also to process the input data.

Comment: If you have binary classification, why you Dense layer has 2 units? It should have 1 unit with sigmoid activation.

Comment: @Sata my last layer is Dense(2, activation='softmax') which is the same as Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'). I tried both layers and did not work

Comment: Dense(2, activation='softmax') is not the same as Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'). Output shapes are different. Can you print model input and output shapes?